# how to create system restore point with rsync

Tags: rsync, restore

i know there is some GUI apps for system restore in Linux such as time shift and systemback
but is there any way to create system restore with rsync?

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple of scripts that generate the following `rsync` command, which works for me.

```
rsync --backup --one-file-system --delete --backup-dir=/backvol/aardvark/archives/2016-12-04-18:57 --stats --archive --ignore-errors / /backvol/aardvark/current
```

My `hostname` is `aardvark`, and my backup disk mounts as `/backvol`.

Comment: ok. what i do for restoring backuped file with this script?